# How Do I Return This JSON Output Out of The "Do" Call In Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, codable, decodable

I've spent the last few hours working on retrieving the contents of a JSON and puts it into an array. Now that I've finally got it, I have no idea how to get the variable "students" that contains the array. I want to be able to return this variable back to the viewDidLoad function. Can you please help?

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {


struct Student: Decodable {
    let Name: String?
    let Gender: String
    let SRT, RST, Accuracy: Double
    let AttentionLevel: Int
    let FavoriteSubject, LeastFavoriteSubject: String

}


struct Student: Decodable {
    let Name: String
    let Score: Int
}
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    getJSONFromOnline()

    
}

func getJSONFromOnline(){
    let jsonURLString = "insert example URL String here" //(I'm using a GitHub Pages site to host the students' data)
    
    let url = URL(string: jsonURLString)
    
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!){
        (data, response, err) in
        
        guard let data = data else {return}
        
        do {
            let students = try JSONDecoder().decode([Student].self, from: data)
            //How do I get this ^^^ variable back to the viewDidLoad function?
        }
        
        catch let jsonErr{
            print("error serializing", jsonErr)
        }
    }.resume()

}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add an `@escaping` completion block to the `getJSONFromOnline` method and use the closure block the get the `students` in `viewDidLoad`.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //...
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        getJSONFromOnline { students in
            print("got students", students)
        }
    }

    func getJSONFromOnline(completion: @escaping ([Student]) -> Void) {
        //...
        let students = try JSONDecoder().decode([Student].self, from: data)
        completion(students)
        //...
    }
}
```

Add-on: It would be better to name the method some a bit more specific, like `getStudents` or `fetchStudents`. Also, move the struct `Student` declaration outside of the `ViewCotroller`.

Comment: you are an absolute magician. That had me going for hours, thank you so much.

Comment: One last bit (sorry) - right underneath view did load, when you're printing the content of "students",  how exactly do you make the "students" variable global? My ultimate goal is to make it global throughout the view controller so I can use it to populate some collectionViews.

Comment: You could declare a optional member variable in the view controller. When you asynchronously fetch the data - you can set the value of this variable. That way it will be available for all of the view controller code once it is loaded. You need to keep it optional as it will not have value initially